# How to handle wit.ai bot using Python

Tags: python, chatbot, wit.ai

How to connect to and handle Wit.ai actions and intents from local machine?
i.e sending query to wit.ai using python api's and performing actions on local machine depend on json response.
I cannot find any proper documentation regarding this.
Almost all the tutorials are using node.js

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, there is a [Python SDK](https://github.com/wit-ai/pywit) on the Wit.ai site.

There are also [few examples](https://github.com/wit-ai/pywit/blob/master/examples/quickstart.py) that should help you get up to speed.

You may first want to check the [quickstart.py](https://wit.ai/docs/quickstart) example, that corresponds to the [Build your first app](https://wit.ai/docs/quickstart) tutorial on the Wit.ai site.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of the [wit.ai](https://wit.ai/) contains the Github repository for python Library [pywit](https://github.com/wit-ai/pywit).

You can check those examples for better understanding of the python code needed to develop chatbot.

Since you asked for documentations and other useful materials, you can check these blogs and github repos

[How to make a basic ChatBot (Wit.ai) Part-1](https://www.codementor.io/srijansaxena/how-to-make-a-basic-chatbot-wit-ai-part-1-7g82j81wu)

[Fb Bot tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x2t9OqTb4kE)  along with integration

Wit.ai API provides many kind of NLP services including Speech Recognition. Follow this [link](https://blog.codingblocks.com/2017/speech-recognition-using-wit-ai) for more information.